# why I get : Failed to compile error after npm start

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, jsx

Trying to test react with typescript, so having this simple and basic component .

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

type AuthUser = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
};

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<null | AuthUser>(null);
  const handleLogin = () => {
    setUser({ name: "momo", email: "momo@es.com" });
  };
  const handleLogout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>login</button>
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>

      <p>my name is {user?.name} </p>
      <p> my email is {user?.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

after runnig the server I got this error :

> Failed to compile
> ./src/App.tsx 49:25
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (49:25)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> columnNumber: 7
> |     }
>
> > }, "my name is ", user?.name, " "), /*#**PURE***/React.createElement("p", {
> > __self: this,
> > __source: {

it seems the issue has something to do with th optional chaining. because changing the part when I acces the user properties like this  :

```
{user && (
        <>
        <p>my name is {user.name} </p>
        <p> my email is {user.email}</p>
        </>
      )}
```

the code work just fine

Comment: I would ensure your react and ts are up to date.

Comment: I believe your working solution is best practice.

Comment: Yeah there the latests versions

Comment: @RoarS. Yeah I think so but the first one is not working it should work  too

Answer (score 0):

it seems I was using `react-scripts  v2`. updating react-scripts to the latest version of `react-scripts 5.0.1`.  and in **tsconfig.json** set `jsx` property set to `react-jsx` solved the error

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
    // ... rest
  },
  // ... rest
}
```